# I need to merge two queries with condition

Tags: oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.CB_LINE as "CB_LINE",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.CB_LINE_DESCRIPTION as "DESCRIPCION",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.UYU_BALANCE_FW as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.USD_BALANCE_FW as "MONEDA EXTRANJERA",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.UYU_BALANCE_COA as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.USD_BALANCE_COA as "MONEDA EXTRANJERA",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.DIFFERENCE_MN as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.DIFFERENCE_ME as " MONEDA EXTRANJERA"
FROM
  TNLRUY.URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H

WHERE
1=1
<#if BOOK_DATE??&& BOOK_DATE?trim !=''> 
AND BOOK_DATE=to_date(:BOOK_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')
</#if>
```

and another query:

```
SELECT
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.CB_LINE as "CB_LINE",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.CB_LINE_DESCRIPTION as "DESCRIPCION",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.UYU_BALANCE_FW as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.USD_BALANCE_FW as "MONEDA EXTRANJERA",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.UYU_BALANCE_COA as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.USD_BALANCE_COA as "MONEDA EXTRANJERA",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.DIFFERENCE_MN as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.DIFFERENCE_ME as " MONEDA EXTRANJERA"
FROM
  TNLRUY.URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H
```

My requirment is that if I enter the `BOOK_DATE` then it should execute the first query, and If I leave `BOOK_DATE` blank then the second query will execute.

Comment: Are you using APEX? Or something else?

Comment: Hi I am using sql developer

Answer (score 1):

Make your where clause operate conditionally based on your input value like this:

```
SELECT
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.CB_LINE as "CB_LINE",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.CB_LINE_DESCRIPTION as "DESCRIPCION",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.UYU_BALANCE_FW as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.USD_BALANCE_FW as "MONEDA EXTRANJERA",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.UYU_BALANCE_COA as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.USD_BALANCE_COA as "MONEDA EXTRANJERA",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.DIFFERENCE_MN as "MONEDA LOCAL",
URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H.DIFFERENCE_ME as " MONEDA EXTRANJERA"
FROM TNLRUY.URYRR_FORWARDS_REC_H
WHERE (:BOOK_DATE IS NULL OR
    (:BOOK_DATE IS NOT NULL AND BOOK_DATE=to_date(:BOOK_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```